# Check whether an specific index has been already used - Bitwise?

Tags: java, java-8, bitwise-operators

I wanna say that I appreciate every contribution on the following problem;
I am currently programming an array shuffler that is shuffling the elements of an array to different randomized positions without changing the instance, so there is no need for revaluating the array field with the returning created array instance (the invocation of that shuffling). I want to create an alternative to other already existing shuffle algorithms like the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm, as an experiment. So I tried several operations but I think I am stuck. I could create an array that stores already used indicies and create a random index that has not been used yet (during the iteration of every element within the array that I want to shuffle). But I want to make this way more cleaner. As the bitwise operations could help me, but just with 2^x hexadecimals.
Here is an example on what I want to achieve and what I've already tried, but simplified:

```
    //Integer that holds information on what indices are being used
    int used = 0;

    //Some indices being used
    used |= 3;
    used |= 4;
    used |= 6;

    //Check whether the 2, 4 are used
    boolean isUsed2 = (used & 2) != 0; //=> false as 2 is not used?
    boolean isUsed4 = (used & 4) != 0; //=> true as 4 is used?
```

So basically what I do not understand is how I can create an integer, that contains information on what specific values have been used and which have not. So to determine if the index 2 or 0 or 8 have been used yet.

Hope my english was understandable.
Sincerly

Comment: You would need an integer as large as 2^n (two to th power n), where n is the length of the array. Or equivalently a bit array. Not practical if n is large.

Comment: You will be soon running out of bits as even a `long` only has 64. If you are going to work with multiple longs, there is no way around an array of them when you want to support real life array sizes. Then, you are reinventing `java.util.BitSet`.

Comment: @Holger yeah that is true, as I said it is just for an experiment. I will not use this publicly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to right-shift your bitMask by index and bitwise and it with 0x1.

```
public boolean getBitState(int bitIndex, int bitMask) {
    return (bitMask >> bitIndex & 0x1) == 0x1;
}
```

true = 1, false = 0

Setting a bit...

```
// returns new bitmask value
    public int setBitState(int bitIndex, boolean value, int bitMask) {
           if (value) {
               return bitMask |= (0x1 << bitIndex);
           } else {
               return bitMask &= ~(0x1 << bitIndex);
           }
    }
```

Comment: added  a setBit method.  I don't entirely know what you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for your contribution! Works now, I seem a little silly don't I? I am not that advanced in bitwise operations. I am very familiar with and & or operations, but not what you've sent with shifting. I am still learning. Thanks!